# How to debug a MultiValueDictKeyError in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django

Here is my template:

```
<form name="myMessage" onsubmit="return validateFormMessage()" method="post" class="signin" action="/profile/message_page">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="title-dl">{% trans "Compose Message" %}</div>
    <div class="dear message_dialog">
        <div><label>{% trans "To" %}</label><input id="to_user" type="text" class="form-control" name = "user_send" />
        </div>
        <div><label>{% trans "Title" %}</label><input type="text" id ="title" class="form-control" name = "title_message"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dl_coin">
        <div class="coin-first"><label>{% trans "Content" %} </label></div>
        <div class="content-message">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="content-message" style="width: 98%;height: 153px;" name="content-message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "fileAttach">
        <i></i><input type = "file" name = "fileAttach">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success dl-submit" value="Send">
    </div>
</form>
```

on `view.py` I use:

```
fileAttach = request.FILES['fileAttach']
```

but I get Error MultiValueDictKeyError. How can I resolve it?

Comment: See [how to write a good title](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes!!! could you help me!!

Answer (score 2):

Add `multipart/form-data` to your `<form>` tag:

```
<form name="myMessage" 
      onsubmit="return validateFormMessage()" 
      method="post" 
      class="signin" 
      action="/profile/message_page"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

> **enctype attribute**
>
> multipart/form-data
>        This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control
>
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Default enctype.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

And in view.py do this:

```
print(request.FILES)
```

> i get Error MultiValueDictKeyError

You can't access a key in a dictionary that doesn't exist.